# How to fill NaN values with 0s and 1s at specified position in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nan

There are variables `V, A, X and O` with two values i.e., `i` and `j` in the form of 0s and 1s.

At first, I used the `i` value for each variable

```
         # i   j
V = 1    # 1   0
A = 0    # 0   1
X = 1    # 1   1
O = 0    # 0   0
```

The dataframe is like this:

```
z = [[V, V, O, V, 1],    
     [V, O, A, 1],
     [X, V, 1],
     [O, 1],
     [1]]

z = pd.DataFrame(z)
zz = z.copy()
zz.index =   ['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5']
zz.columns = ['C5','C4','C3','C2','C1']

cols=z.columns.tolist()
cols.sort(reverse=True)
df=z[cols]
df.index = ['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5']
df.columns = ['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5']
df

     C1  C2  C3  C4  C5     # Here 'V','A','X','O' are replaced by their i values. 
C1   1   1   0   1   1
C2  NaN  1   0   0   1
C3  NaN NaN  1   1   1
C4  NaN NaN NaN  1   0
C5  NaN NaN NaN NaN  1
```

Now, I need to fill NaN values with their respective `j` values.
The logic is like this, if row C1, Column C2 is having i value then row C2, column C1 must fill NaN with j value of the corresponding variable. Similarly I want to use this logic for all rows and columns

The output I need:

```
    C1   C2  C3  C4  C5
C1   1   1   0   1   1
C2   0   1   0   0   1
C3   0   1   1   1   1
C4   0   0   0   1   0
C5   0   0   1   0   1
```

Comment: and according to which logic do you map the j values?

Comment: The logic is like this, if row C1, Column C2 is having i value then row C2, column C1 must have j value

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71407903/edit) the question, don't use comments

Comment: I have modified my question. Please check it. Thanks!

Comment: My output is different. Is possible explain why is replaced missing values for `C3, C2` and not for `C3, C1` or `C3, C3` ?

Comment: I am sorry j value of `O` is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
         # i   j
V = 1    # 1   0
A = 0    # 0   1
X = 1    # 1   1
O = 0    # 0   1


z = [[V, V, O, V, 1],    
     [V, O, A, 1],
     [X, V, 1],
     [O, 1],
     [1]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(z, index=['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5'], columns=['C5','C4','C3','C2','C1'])
```

---

```
         # i   j
V = 0    # 1   0
A = 1    # 0   1
X = 1    # 1   1
O = 1    # 0   1

z = [[V, V, O, V, 1],    
     [V, O, A, 1],
     [X, V, 1],
     [O, 1],
     [1]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(z, columns=['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5'], index=['C5','C4','C3','C2','C1'])
```

---

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2).astype(int)
print (df)
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
C1   1   1   0   1   1
C2   1   1   0   0   1
C3   1   0   1   1   1
C4   0   1   1   1   0
C5   0   0   1   0   1
```